# Why does this Perl variable keep its value

Tags: perl, variables, initialization, declaration

What is the difference between the following two Perl variable declarations?

```
my $foo = 'bar' if 0;

my $baz;
$baz = 'qux' if 0;
```

The difference is significant when these appear at the top of a loop. For example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

foreach my $n (0,1){
    my $foo = 'bar' if 0;
    print defined $foo ? "defined\n" : "undefined\n";
    $foo = 'bar';
    print defined $foo ? "defined\n" : "undefined\n";
}

print "==\n";

foreach my $m (0,1){
    my $baz;
    $baz = 'qux' if 0;
    print defined $baz ? "defined\n" : "undefined\n";
    $baz = 'qux';
    print defined $baz ? "defined\n" : "undefined\n";
}
```

results in

```
undefined
defined
defined
defined
==
undefined
defined
undefined
defined
```

It seems that `if 0` fails, so `foo` is never reinitialized to `undef`. In this case, how does it get declared in the first place?

Comment: `perl -MO=Deparse yourfile` prints those `if 0` lines as `'???';`, and the output, recompiled, dies for want of explicit package names.  So I'd conclude that such constructions should be avoided, that if Perl had a standard this would be noted as exercising undefined behavior, etc.  But maybe someone will provide the perlguts explanation.

Comment: @Julian Fondren, `'???'` just means the code was optimized away. (e.g. `perl -MO=Deparse -e"1,2,3"` and `perl -MO=Deparse -le"print 'abc' if 0;"` show question marks even though both snippets are perfectly legit.) Deparse showing question marks for `my $x if 0`; would be a bug if `my $x if 0;` was allowed since `my` has a compile-time effect, though it's true that its runtime effect is optimized away.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, note that `my $foo = 'bar' if 0;` is documented to be undefined behaviour, meaning it's allowed to do anything including crash. But I'll explain what happens anyway.

---

`my $x` has three documented effects:

- It declares a symbol at compile-time.
- It creates an new variable on execution.
- It returns the new variable on execution.

In short, it's suppose to be like Java's `Scalar x = new Scalar();`, except it returns the variable if used in an expression.

But if it actually worked that way, the following would create 100 variables:

```
for (1..100) {
   my $x = rand();
   print "$x\n";
}
```

This would mean two or three memory allocations per loop iteration for the `my` alone! A very expensive prospect. Instead, Perl only creates one variable and clears it at the end of the scope. So in reality, `my $x` actually does the following:

- It declares a symbol at compile-time.
- It creates the variable at compile-time<sup>[1]</sup>.
- It puts a directive on the stack that will clear<sup>[2]</sup> the variable when the scope is exited.
- It returns the new variable on execution.

As such, only one variable is ever created<sup>[2]</sup>. This is much more CPU-efficient than then creating one every time the scope is entered.

Now consider what happens if you execute a `my` conditionally, or never at all. By doing so, you are preventing it from placing the directive to clear the variable on the stack, so the variable never loses its value. Obviously, that's not meant to happen, so that's why `my ... if ...;` isn't allowed.

---

Some take advantage of the implementation as follows:

```
sub foo {
   my $state if 0;
   $state = 5 if !defined($state);
   print "$state\n";
   ++$state;
}

foo();  # 5
foo();  # 6
foo();  # 7
```

But doing so requires ignoring the documentation forbidding it. The above can be achieved safely using

```
{
   my $state = 5;
   sub foo {
      print "$state\n";
      ++$state;
   }
}
```

or

```
use feature qw( state );  # Or: use 5.010;

sub foo {
   state $state = 5;
   print "$state\n";
   ++$state;
}
```

---

Notes:

1. "Variable" can mean a couple of things. I'm not sure which definition is accurate here, but it doesn't matter.
2. If anything but the sub itself holds a reference to the variable (REFCNT>1) or if variable contains an object, the directive replaces the variable with a new one (on scope exit) instead of clearing the existing one. This allows the following to work as it should:

   ```
   my @a;
   for (...) {
       my $x = ...;
       push @a, \$x;
   }
   ```

Comment: I still don't understand why _some_ of the `my` behaviour works (we don't get `Global symbol "$foo" requires explicit package name` later on) but some doesn't (directive to clear the variable on the stack).

Comment: As he said, the lexical/global distinction happens at compile time and is not affected by the conditional.  The clear directive is a run time behavior and is disabled by an `if 0`.

Comment: @ajwood, The variable declaration happens at compile-time (where it doesn't matter if the code is ever run), and the clearing happens at run-time (where it does matter). -ikegami

Comment: On note 1, it is no longer accurate.  There actually appears to be a hack to do different things if the conditional is always false, or merely can be false.  Try `perl -wle 'sub foo {my $state = shift if @_; print $state} foo(); foo(5); foo()'` to see what I mean.  This fixes the common hard to find bugs from the old way of doing things.  (And I have a heartfelt thank you to whoever fixed it!)

Comment: @btilly, The code you gave prints the same thing from Perl 5.8 (earliest I have) to 5.19.5 (lastest that exists). I don't know what change you think happened, but your code doesn't prove it.

Comment: @btilly, Nothing I said has changed since I said it, especially not note 1. `perl -E'{ my $x = 123; sub f { print $x } } f()'` prints `123`. `f` captured `$x` at compile-time, so `$x` must have existed at compile-time.

Comment: @ikegami When I first encountered this feature in 2000, the third call to foo() would still have the value 5 stored in $state.  I found the behavior in Perl 5.003 to 5.6, and encountered it as a bug in a CPAN module.  I am fairly sure that I tested it on an early iteration of 5.8 and found the same behavior many years ago.  But when I tried it on 5.14, the run-time initialization happened on the third call despite @_ being false on that call.

Comment: @btilly, Maybe you were thinking of `sub f { my $s if $_[0]; print $s if $_[0]; $s = $_[1]; }  f(0,123); f(1);`, which still prints the previous pass's value.

Comment: @ikegami I am positive that the code that I gave was broken as of my original bug report in 2000.  And I think it was broken when I tried it early in the 5.8 series.  But I could be mistaken about the latter.

Comment: @btilly, Just tried it with 5.6.0. Exact same result as the latest Perl. I'm not sure what you're thinking of, but your comments to this answer are not useful.

Answer (score -1):

See ikegami's better answer, probably above.

In the first example, you never define $foo inside the loop because of the conditional, so when you use it, you're referencing and then assigning a value to an implicitly declared global variable. Then, the second time through the loop that outside variable is already defined.

In the second example, $baz is defined inside the block each time the block is executed. So the second time through the loop it is a new, not yet defined, local variable.

Comment: Shouldn't `use warnings` or `use strict` have something to say about that though? They don't.

Comment: "an implicitly declared variable in the containing scope".  er, which to say, a package variable.  But he's not, as you can see by giving `$::foo` and `$::baz` a value and printing them when the `defined` passes.  And when there is a lexical variable outside these loops that they could refer to, the same measure shows that the behavior doesn't change for either loop.

Comment: There's no such thing as "implicitly declared variable in the containing scope". Implicit;y declared variables are package variables which are global. Both `$foo` and `$baz` are lexical variables. See my answer for what's actually happening.