# Is "my" a function in Perl?

Tags: perl

I know that `my` is used to declare a variable local to a block or file. I have always assumed that `my` is a *keyword* in Perl. But I was just told that it's actually a function. One of the proofs is that `perldoc` puts `my` under the “Functions” section, see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html.

How does a function do the job of declaring local variables?

Comment: That argument doesn't mean much, `import` (a special subroutine) and `qr` (an operator) are also listed there.

Comment: @daxim The book [Beginning Perl](http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Perl-Curtis-Poe/dp/1118013840/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1372402328&sr=8-1&keywords=Beginning+Perl) also say `my` is a function, but didn't give much explanations.

Comment: That book is also wrong, then. `my` is very definitely not a function.

Comment: Does it matter what you call it? Note that the word `local` has special meaning in Perl, too :)

Comment: @briandfoy I don't care what to call it. But if it were a function, I'd like to know how it works. Since it's not, there's no problem for me then.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, by Perl's (very unique) definition, `my` is a function. The opening paragraph of [perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html) defines "function":

> The functions in this section can serve as terms in an expression. They fall into two major categories: list operators and named unary operators.

`my` is a named operator. But it's special in two ways:

- In addition to behaving like a function (that allocates a new variable and returns that variable), it has a compile-time effect.
- `my ...` is a unary operator, but it can accept multiple arguments when parens are used.

---

If on the other hand you were ask if `my` was a function by C's definition, then no. `my` is not a C function. Neither is `print`, `open`, `chr`, etc. Everything in perlfunc is an operator; none of them are functions.

---

Finally, `print`, `open` and `chr` are far closer to a person's conception of a function than `my`. To be more precise, few people would consider `my` to be a function. It's more of a technicality than anything meaningful that it matches perfunc's definition of function.

---

See also:

- [What are perl built-in operators/functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7167873/2525443)
- [Why does this [`my`] variable keep its value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17357053/2525443)

Answer (score 16):

`my` is *not* a function, it's just clumped together with functions (in perl documentation) because it works like a function.

If you look at [`perldoc perlfunc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#Perl-Functions-by-Category), it is saith,

> Here are Perl's functions (including things that look like functions, like some keywords and named operators) arranged by category...

then a bit below that

> Keywords related to scoping
>   `caller`, `import`, `local`, `my`, `our`, `package`, `state`, `use`

Specifically, note that the word “keyword” was used there instead of “function”

So that implies that you would find some non-functions (e.g. keywords) under [Perl functions A-Z](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-functions.html)

Another way of saying this: if something is listed under “Functions” in perldoc, it is not necessarily a function – it can be a keyword or named operator which acts like a function.

Comment: Huh, I thought caller *is* a function. At least it behaves like a function, and not like a keyword/operator.

Comment: @Dallaylaen, Hey, perldoc's words, not mine :). But I do agree that `caller` behaves more like a function.

Comment: Re "So that implies that you would find some non-functions (e.g. keywords) under Perl functions A-Z". They're all named operators (as mentioned in the page's second sentence), which means they're all keywords. (Well, they could be reserved words, but Perl doesn't have any.)